# JavaScript: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, object, typeerror

I have a script that gets the value of a certain fields (Advanced Custom Field), adds a split symbol, reorders the values, and finally converts it to a proper date. It's been working great up until today. I haven't made any changes to the site, but all of a sudden I get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'fromField.replace')
```

Here's the code:

```
var fromField = $("div[data-name='renting_from'] .input-alt").val();
fromField = fromField.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1/$2/$3');


var toField = $("div[data-name='renting_to'] .input-alt").val();
toField = toField.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1/$2/$3');


fromField = new Date(fromField);
toField = new Date(toField);
```

I didn't write the code, I'm just helping the owners of the website out. I'm at a bit of a loss here, to be honest, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Someone probably changed the structure of the HTML so the selector is not finding the right element anymore.  Make sure the structure is still the same

Comment: Can you post the HTML form?

Comment: @TravisJames You were absolutely right. Perhaps Advanced Custom Fields changed the structure of the HTML in an update or something.